# How to input a network file to ffmpeg

Tags: ssh, scp, ffmpeg

My problem is this. I have access to a server that hosts many video files, most of them are very large and not well compressed. I intend to make a reduced quality smaller size copy of these on my local machine for better access.

The problem is that the server does not have ftp access. I can scp the files to my machine and then use ffmpeg to reduce the size, but I'll run out of space if I copy all of the files locally.

I am looking for a way to directly input a network file to ffmpeg, that way I'll be able to write a script that will overnight get me all the videos in reduced size.

Comment: You should edit the question : As it stands, its a "XYProblem": asking to do Y, when you really want to do X. You really want to input a network file remotely, not "using scp" (It sounds like: "how can I shave my beard using a bycicle" : the real need is shaving the beard, not really using a bycicle ^^) Don't mix your need with the means to do so (so that you can find better means, using people's feedback!)

Comment: See answers by Flup and cpugeniusmv for the right ways to do it. However, if you have a network bottleneck, it would make sense to compress on the server-side and then transfer the compressed version over network (if ffmpeg exists on that machine).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `sshfs` to make the remote files appear in a directory on the local machine.

You don't say what distro you're using on your client, but this is cribbed from [the Ubuntu sshfs documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS):

1. Install the `sshfs` package (`aptitude install sshfs`)
2. Add your user to the `fuse` group (`sudo gpasswd -a username fuse`)
3. Mount the filesystem using the `sshfs` command

To use `sshfs`, make yourself a directory (we'll call this `/mountpoint`), and do

```
sshfs -o idmap=user remote_user@remote_server:/remote/directory /mountpoint
```

The remote files will now appear in `/mountpoint`, but are in fact still on the remote server.  Any changes you make will be made remotely and not locally.

To unmount the directory, do

```
fusermount -u /mountpoint
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have ssh access to the remote system, you could do something like

`ssh server cat path/to/video | ffmpeg -i - [...]`

The `-` causes ffmpeg to read from stdin instead of a file.

Caveat, though, not all formats support pipes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999674/ffmpeg-which-file-formats-support-stdin-usage

Comment: The video device might not support the block size used by 'cat' - if you get an error, use 'nc' instead of 'cat' - see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46362136/1755628